# Downloading Schema from GraphiQL

Tags: graphiql

I am currently using the apollo android and iOs libraries which require me to download the schema. Is it possible to download the schema from graphiql? Currently, I keep getting errors from the command line and there is no way to download it manually from the GraphiQL interface. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes Its possible to download the schema from `graphiql`, but when you download manually it may be in old json format.(in my case that was the problem).

so you can add this scrip to your build phase run script ( when you use SPM, check for others -> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation/#adding-a-code-generation-build-step ). then the CLI will download the correct one for you automatically.

```
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh schema:download --endpoint="https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/"
```

**Note:**  you need to change the endpoint url according to yours.

After you build the xcode project once ,then you can remove this line from the build script.

Comment: Thank you @Yodagama would this old json format cause problems when running the queries? The reason I ask is because I was able to get the schema outside of xcode scripts and now i am seeing a 400 error when making calls

Comment: is 400 networking error code or compiler error code ?